# JQuery .hover slideDown slideUp working but ,click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have a dropdown menu. Instead of using the default animation I have used a JQuery `slideDown` and `slideUp`. Only issue I am having is when I hover it works fine but when I click the menu it displays properly and `slidesDown` works, second click then `slideUP` works, then on the third click to check if will work again, there is no response. I have seen many examples and different methods but I am a novice and haven't had much luck.

Relevant Code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hover(function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
      $(this).addClass('open');
   }, function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
      $(this).removeClass('open');
   }); 
});
```

Relevant Code that does't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').click(function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
      $(this).addClass('open');
   }, function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
      $(this).removeClass('open');
   }); 
});
```

In the end I would like to add `$('#target').on('click hover', function () {` so if the user hovers over the menu and accidentally clicks, it closes the menu and they can reopen by either hovering over it again or clicking it open.

I'm not sure how to remove the hover function when clicking.

Comment: click takes only one param....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method takes only one parameter as its argument. You can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').click(function () {
      $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle('fast');
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hover takes two functions as parameters: (http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
jQuery.hover(onHoverIn, onHoverOut);
```

Click only takes one. (http://api.jquery.com/click/)

You would need to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').click(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
         $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(100);
         $(this).removeClass('open');
      } else {
         $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
         $(this).addClass('open');
      }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. This may be worth noting, I have both the hover and click function at the same time. The `slideToggle` worked but adding `.hasClass` did nothing. Thanks for the references though, good to know

Comment: Is there something in the `hover` function that might be messing with it? Because the above code is tested and works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/2d8w1L0k/

Comment: Weird. Your solution works here, http://jsfiddle.net/2d8w1L0k/2/ when I add my extra bits and pieces in but it doesn't work on my site. Maybe something is messing about. But thanks for the solution, will save it for future projects